# Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "map", sizes is undefined

Tags: reactjs, mapping

I am trying to map the prop sizes, that I'm saving in a state when the item has been loaded from the api, but I keep getting this error:
*"Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "map", sizes is undefined"*

```
    const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
    const { id } = useParams()
    const [item, setItem] = useState({})
    const [related, setRelated] = useState([])
    const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    const getRelated = () => {
        const relatedItems = (productList.filter(product => product.category === item.category))
        const clearRelated = relatedItems.filter(product => product.id !== item.id)
        setRelated(clearRelated)
    }

    const setsizing = () => {
        setSizes(item.sizes)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        customFetch(3000, productList.find(product => product.id == id))
            .then(res => setItem(res))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
            .finally(setLoading(false))
    }, [])

    //This is a solution to get the sizes and related items to load after the item has been loaded
    useEffect(() => {
        getRelated()
        setsizing()
        console.log(sizes);
    }, [item])



    return (
        <>
            loading ? <Spinner />
            :
            <ItemDetail
                name={item.name}
                price={item.price}
                img={item.img}
                stock={item.stock}
                category={item.category}
                description={item.description}
                sizes={sizes}
                related={related}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: you can't access state value as soon as you call 'set' state function. `setsizing()
        console.log(sizes);`, Where is map?

Comment: Oh okay, map is inside my ItemDetail component, it just maps the sizes for making a form

Comment: I posted a basic answer you can refer to. If you post the correct code, I can explain more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in usage of React hook.

**1. You should not access state variable as soon as you set the state. Because value is not reliable at all.**

```
        setsizing()
        console.log(sizes); // This sizes is not updated value in Reactjs.
```

**2. You should provide correct dependencies in your hooks and can remove unnecessary functions.**

In the following code, you need to add productList at least.

```
useEffect(() => {
        customFetch(3000, productList.find(product => product.id == id))
            .then(res => setItem(res))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
            .finally(setLoading(false))
    }, [])
```

**3. You can write one line code to get the related list.**

Here is the updated code snippet you can refer to.

```
const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const [item, setItem] = useState({})
  const [related, setRelated] = useState([])
  const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    customFetch(3000, productList.find(product => product.id == id))
      .then(res => setItem(res))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      .finally(setLoading(false))
  }, [productList])

  //This is a solution to get the sizes and related items to load after the item has been loaded
  useEffect(() => {
    if (item && productList) {
      const related = (productList.filter(product => product.category === item.category && product.id !== item.id))
      setRelated(related);
      setSizes(item.sizes);
    }
  }, [item, productList]);

  return (
    <>
      loading ? <Spinner />
      :
      (item? <ItemDetail
        name={item.name}
        price={item.price}
        img={item.img}
        stock={item.stock}
        category={item.category}
        description={item.description}
        sizes={sizes}
        related={related}
      /> : <div>Item does not exist!</div>)
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I implemented your code but i keep getting that error. This is the github repo, if you want to access to all my code, the .map is in the ItemDetail component.
https://github.com/ManuelNelson7/bacall-store

Comment: my bad, it wasn't pushed, now it is

Comment: let me review your code.

Comment: @ManuelNelson well, there is no error and I can run it on dev mode. What's wrong?

Comment: @ManuelNelson but you need to remove `items` in `useEffect` in ItemListContainer. Final code `useEffect(() => {
        customFetch(1000, productList)
            .then(res => setItems(res))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, [])`

Comment: @ManuelNelson, see this : [https://www.screencast.com/t/8IBudq4uQBzg](https://www.screencast.com/t/8IBudq4uQBzg)